# Error message in restoring database

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, database-backups, database-restore, error-log

I saw this error message occurs during a restore operation, I check database integrity in source server with Ola Hallengren script, database is OK.

Error-Log
[image]

Error
[image]

Comment: There is no question here. What is it that you are asking?

Comment: why could not restore database normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved

```
RESTORE DATABASE My_DB FROM 
DISK = 'D:\My_DB.bak' WITH MOVE 'My_DB_Data' TO 'D:\Data\My_DB_Data.mdf', 
MOVE 'My_DB_Data_New_01' TO 'D:\Data\My_DB_Data_New_01.ndf',
MOVE 'My_DB_Data_Current_01' TO 'D:\Data\My_DB_Data_Current_01.ndf',
MOVE 'My_DB_Data_Current_02' TO 'D:\Data\My_DB_Data_Current_02.ndf', 
MOVE 'My_DB_Log' TO 'F:\Log\My_DB_Log.ldf' ,keep_cdc, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
```

for more information
[check this link](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/140758/error-message-in-restoring-database.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an update is required. 
Please refer to the relevant link: 
[HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/980832)

Comment: i use Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2)